# Objective-C remove UIButton from Superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, afnetworking, superview

I have this UIButton defined in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *loginButton;

- (void)LoginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
```

and have it created in my .m file:

```
@synthesize loginButton;

loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[loginButton setFrame:CGRectMake(150.0f, 131.0f, 105.0f, 35.0f)];
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(LoginButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)LoginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self CreateActivityIndicator];
    [self performSelector:@selector(Login) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
```

and I have a method called login and on login I want to remove the login button from superview.

```
[self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
```

but all of a sudden (as of yesterday) my app started crashing and throwing an error on this line:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *loginButton;

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0x10000010)
```

Why is this happening? and how can I fix it? I did change my login method around yesterday to use AFNetworking, could that be it?

Just in case, here is my full method:

```
- (void)Login
{
    NSString *rawString = [self.idTextField text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [self.idTextField setText:[rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]];

    [userName UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (responseObject) {
            [self.idTextField removeFromSuperview];
            [self.passwordTextField removeFromSuperview];
            [self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
            self.idTextField = nil;
            self.passwordTextField = nil;
            self.loginButton = nil;
            [self CreateMenu];
        }else{
            [self CustomAlert:@"Sorry Login Failed, User and/or Passsword Incorrect"];
        }
    }];

    [indicatorView stopAnimating];
    [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
    indicatorView = nil;
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    loadingView = nil;

}
```

and here is what is triggering it:

```
-(void)UserLogin:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *resultsObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
{


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];


    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential
                                   credentialWithUser:user
                                   password:password
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [operation setCredential:credential];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Here is how my button is getting added to the view, along with the 2 text items:

```
//add all controls to the loginView
        [loginMenuView addSubview:self.idTextField];
        [loginMenuView addSubview:self.passwordTextField];
        [loginMenuView addSubview:self.loginButton];
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to resolve this issue by doing the following:

taking out `self.loginButton = nil;` from my Login Method, so it looks like this:

```
- (void)Login
{
    NSString *rawString = [self.idTextField text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [self.idTextField setText:[rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]];


    [userName UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (responseObject) {

                [self.idTextField removeFromSuperview];
                [self.passwordTextField removeFromSuperview];
                [self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
                self.idTextField = nil;
                self.passwordTextField = nil;
                //self.loginButton = nil;


                [self CreateMenu];



                [indicatorView stopAnimating];
                [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
                indicatorView = nil;
                [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
                loadingView = nil;
        }else{


            [self CustomAlert:@"Sorry Login Failed, User and/or Passsword Incorrect"];

            [indicatorView stopAnimating];
            [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
            indicatorView = nil;
            [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
            loadingView = nil;

        }
    }];

}
```

and taking out `[self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];` and `self.loginButton = nil;` from my `viewWillDisappear` method like so:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    userName = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
    [self.idTextField removeFromSuperview];
    [self.passwordTextField removeFromSuperview];
    //[self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
    [self.menu removeFromSuperview];
    [logoutButton removeFromSuperview];
    //set every control to nil
    self.idTextField = nil;
    self.passwordTextField = nil;
    //self.loginButton = nil;
    self.menu = nil;
    menuItems = nil;
    textfieldNavigatorView = nil;
}
```

this has solved my problem, I just want to know if this is the best solution.

Comment: Would you like to consider just hiding your button? If not i will explain the problem.

Comment: I would consider hiding the button, but I would also like to know what the problem is

Comment: You seem to stop the indicator and remove it along with a loading view  before the completion handler has finished. Should that not code not be in the completion handler.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel What would that look like ?

Comment: I was assuming that when you press login, that you want to show its busy until you actually receive the login success or failure. At the moment in your `Login`, you are stopping the activity right after your execute the UserLogin operation, so will show no activity indicator until a response is received which could take some time. I imagine if the login operation is fast it looks ok. Other than from a logic perspective, my concern was that the indicator  and loading view removal was causing your issue when executed early.

Comment: The error would imply that `self` is nolonger valid inside the completion block.

Comment: How come the text items get removed from superView and not the button?

Comment: @user979331 You could try moving the button removal to before the text items are removed to see if it still crashes at the exact same place or if it moves. Probably need to see more code to help farther. Out of interest: In the code you have shown, you do not actually add the button to the view.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I added the code that adds the button and text to the view.

Comment: You should not be using @synthesize. You shouldn't be using it at all. Don't using it. Remove it from your projects. Anything you've done for the past 4 years shouldn't be using it. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that your loginButton is tied to your indicatorView or loadingView.

Since you're using a completion handler, the code inside of it is going to run asynchronously. That means that your

```
indicatorView = nil
```

or your

```
loadingView = nil
```

is being triggered before your loginButton is being removed. If loginButton is a subview of one of those views, nothing has reference to it anymore, thus you get a BAD_ACCESS. Make sure you put the last 5 lines of code (the ones that deal with loadingView and indicatorView) inside of your completion handler like so:

```
- (void)Login
{
NSString *rawString = [self.idTextField text];
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
[self.idTextField setText:[rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]];

[userName UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (responseObject) {


        [self.idTextField removeFromSuperview];
        [self.passwordTextField removeFromSuperview];
        //access the loginButton while it still has reference
        [self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
        self.idTextField = nil;
        self.passwordTextField = nil;
        //access the loginButton while it still has reference
        self.loginButton = nil;

        //Then remove these views
        [indicatorView stopAnimating];
        [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
        indicatorView = nil;
        [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
        loadingView = nil;

        [self CreateMenu];
    }else{
        [self CustomAlert:@"Sorry Login Failed, User and/or Passsword Incorrect"];
    }
}];

}
```